# How to replace start date and end date for multiple row data with the maximum and minimum of date in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oraclereports

I have a multiple rows data with unique start date and end date combination.

I want to replace the start date with the minimum of all the start dates
and End date with maximum of all the end dates.

Example:

```
id         start Date    end Date


1005    09/01/2000  05/31/2001

1005    09/05/2000  05/23/2001

100775  03/15/2005  04/30/2005

100775  03/25/2005  04/22/2005

3273    09/01/2003  12/31/2004

3273    09/11/2003  12/11/2004
```

Now I want the output to look like:

```
id         start Date    end date


1005    09/01/2000  05/31/2001

1005    09/01/2000  05/31/2001

100775  03/15/2005  04/30/2005

100775  03/15/2005  04/30/2005

3273    09/01/2003  12/31/2004

3273    09/01/2003  12/31/2004
```

I have tried doing this with `max` and `min` functions but that doesn't work since I want this to be only one query for using it in oracle report builder.

Comment: Were you not able to use the OVER expression with the min and Max commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just use `min` and `max` function  to get your desired output:

```
select
        id,
        min(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id)  start_date,
        max(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id)  end_date 
FROM table1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/acdc7b/1/0)

Comment: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected While executing the query suggested.

Comment: Sorry about that, I missed the keyword `SET`. It should work for you now. :)

Comment: I'm not sure wer'e really talking about an update here even though OP used the word "replace".

Comment: @shawnt00  I agree, the word `replace` could be interpreted in many ways here. Also, the OP specifically mentions `I have a multiple rows data with unique start date and end date combination.` So, this could only be taken as that he is looking to update the existing records in the table?

Comment: @FutbolFan I don't think I read anything in that sentence regarding update vs select. But I would also note the reference to "output" (which is still potentially ambiguous) and "report builder" (which probably is not.)

Comment: @shawnt00 I need to extract a table from the query. I don't want to update. Thanks

Comment: @vamsikrishna I have updated my answer with shawnt00's suggestion and also included an example of your output. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks everyone my issue is resolved now. I am grateful to you guys :)

Comment: Awesome! Please feel free to mark this as accepted answer as this will allow others to know this question has been resolved. Thanks!

Comment: @SVK It makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this,

```
UPDATE T1 SET StartDate = MinStartDate, EndDate = MaxEndDate
FROM  (
    Select id, min(StartDate) as 'MinStartDate',
    Max(EndDate) as 'MaxEndDate'
    from T1 
    Group by id
    ) AS T2
WHERE  T1.id = T2.id;
```

Comment: I need to extract a table from the query. I don't want to update. Thanks for suggestion though